# Media query doesn't override tag style

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to override `h1` tag's `font-size`, but it won't do it
I have some specification for the `h1` tag, but not for it's font-size:

```
#carousel-index .carousel-inner .item .slide_info h1 {
    color: #005e9c;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

and for font size I have this

```
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

and this is my media query

```
@media (max-width: 1224px){
    h1{
        font-size:30px;
    }
}
```

but it's still 36px instead of 30px

Comment: What is the order of the rules in your css-file? Is the mediaquery ***after*** the basic h1-rule?

Comment: And the width of you browserwindow is more than 1224px?
For debugging try to use a smaler value.

Comment: look here http://i.imgur.com/M8Aa4L5.png I think the h1 rule is written in bootstrap, I'll check

Comment: they are in separate files, how can i check that? should i include bootstrap before my style?

Comment: @Cr1xus What order are the references in your html? Is bootsraps css before the css-file with the media query?

Comment: yes I put the bootstrap.less before mystyle in the html include, now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media queries have to be after the 'standard' rules:

```
h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 1224px){
    h1{
        font-size:30px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

See this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ej6phmj1/

Comment: you're right, my problem was the order i included the css files, thank you and thank you @Esko

Answer (score 0):

The `@media` rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices and it have given syntax.
The proper CSS Syntax should be:

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

In your case:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1224px){
    h1, .h1{
        font-size:30px;
    }
}
```

Also, depending of the order of CSS rules (i.e. the way browser interprets them) you may need to add `!important;` after font-size.

Comment: The "only screen" filter is not obligatory

Answer (score 0):

You can force an override by using `!important`

```
@media (max-width: 1224px){
h1{
    font-size:30px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: This would work but !important should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: @remib no you're right. Not "as much", just "always" imho